# Finding change maximum change in the value using Redshift

Tags: data-analysis, redshift

Following is the problem I want to solve. But I don't know how to implement it. I am using Redshift to store data.

Following is the format of the data stored in Redshift. It is sales history for every product for all year by month.

```
ProductId   Year    Month   Sales
A           2018    1       ...
A           2018    2       ...
A           2018    3       ...
A           2018    4       ...
A           2018    5       ...
B           2018    1       ...
B           2018    2       ...
B           2018    3       ...
B           2018    4       ...
B           2018    5       ...
....
....
....
```

Let's assume following are the sales chart of Product A, B and C. Each line represent sales in different year. I have a query: "Sales of which product increases in the month of October".
The answer should be Product A followed by B. (Product A has fewer sales then Product B but percent change in sales value of Product A is higher)

How can I extract such a pattern from the data?

[image: Product A sales chart]

[image: Product B sales chart]

[image]

Comment: "Sales of which product increases in the month of October" with respect to what? From the preceding month? And in what year? If you want to see increase with respect to its previous month, then subtract the sales of each month from its preceding month, and plot all the Products in one graph to compare easily.

Comment: With respect to other months of the same product, both preceding and following months. Which year? The pattern for all year.